# PHP dollar sign in strings

Tags: php

I don't unserstand why PHP doesn't make replacements in strings containing dollar signs.
Look at the following example:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
$var = 1024;
$str = '$var';
echo $str, '<br>', "$str";
```

Output is *$var $var*. Why is it so? Everything is clear with first `echo` parameter, but I expected that the last parameter will give a different result (1024), because it contains dollar sign encapsulated by double quotes, so it should be interpreted as variable and replaced to 1024. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php before asking the question?

Comment: Sure. _When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it._ I thought that $str content should be interpreted as a variable.

Comment: yes. it was interpreted as `$str` which holds the string `'$var'`.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that this is not bacause of, for example, configuration settings, escaping dollar signs under such conditions.

Comment: I think this was a misunderstanding. By "double quotes" the manual means "double quotes", not a string enclosed by (two) 'single quotes'. The manual language could be more clear ... "of the type shown"; other languages use different quotes for everyday speech.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$str` contains a string with the content of `"$var"` (no variable replacement, just these very characters). It was created using single quotes, so no variable replacement there.

When echoing it using `echo "$str"`, the variable `$str` gets replaced with its content, namely the string `"$var"`, thus resulting in your output.

The string replacement in double quotes strings does not work recursively! So in order to have `$str` replaced by `1024`  in the second appearance, you have to create `$str` using double quotes in the first place.

Comment: You can also escape the dollar sign: `"pas\$word"`.

Answer (score 7):

`"` allows you to place variables inside string.

`'` takes everything inside just as a string.

So, if you do `'$var'` - it's string with `$` inside.

`"$str"` takes `$str` value so it prints `$var`

Answer (score 1):

$str contains the literal string $var, which will not be interpreted ever, since it is between single quotes.

To interpret it, you need eval()

```
eval($str)
```

will output 1042

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php
  error_reporting (E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
  $var = 1024;
  $str = $var;
  echo $str, '<br>', "$str";
```

Output -

1024

1024

hehe

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow.  Old code-only answers inspire new code-only answers.  Please role model better answering by editing this answer to include some explanation.