# Echo $ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to echo a string in java script like this

```
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('User registeration Complete \n User Number: $account_number\n First Name: $first_name\n Last Name: $last_name')
window.location.href='index.html';
</SCRIPT>");
```

Challenge i have is I want it to echo an assigned variable say `$name='Samil';` and it prints the $name on Javascript alertbox.

Comment: u want to print ```<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('User registeration Complete \n User Number: $account_number\n First Name: $first_name\n Last Name: $last_name')
window.location.href='index.html';
</SCRIPT>"``` statement .right???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP dollar sign in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246822/php-dollar-sign-in-strings)

Comment: @AyushBansal yes

Comment: If you are in a php page script, you can add <?=$variable?> and it will echo out your variables value within the JS/jQuery script

Comment: @JamesIbrahimov try my answer below

Comment: Is this code from 1995? The `language` attribute on script tags is long since deprecated, it should be `type="text/javascript"`. Also, writing tags with capital letters is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sequence of `'` and `"`:

```
echo ('
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   window.alert("User registeration Complete \n User Number: '.$account_number.'\n First Name: '.$first_name.'\n Last Name: '.$last_name.'")
   window.location.href="index.html";
</SCRIPT>
');
```

Comment: You the Boss!. Thank you Much Much.

Comment: You can also escape your double quotes like so `\"something\"`: `echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">window.alert("User registration Complete \n User Number: \".$account_number.\
"\n First Name.... etc`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo"
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   window.alert('User registeration Complete \n User Number: ".$account_number."\n First Name: ".$first_name."\n Last Name: ".$last_name."')
   window.location.href='index.html';
</SCRIPT>
";
```

> *Note: The language attribute on script tags is deprecated and should be `type="text/javascript"`*

Comment: Thanks for your Help.

Comment: @JamesIbrahimov You're welcome :) Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you